# centos 5.5; yum broken; need command line subversion client (will be retrieving files from a remote repository)

Tags: svn, centos5, yum

Evidently, getting subversion would be a piece of cake, if only yum weren't broken.  Moreover, just about everywhere I search for info on installing subversion takes it for granted that yum is available for the task.

The story on yum is that, before I knew better, I upgraded python to 2.7 and am now getting the infamous "...No module named yum..." message in response to the yum command.

Of course, I'd like to have yum working; however, my immediate need is to get a subversion client going.  How do I do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If yum is broken, you can still download the rpms from the repository mirrors manually and use the `rpm` command to install them.

You might have to have a few attempts with the raw rpm command to find out (and satisfy) all the svn package dependencies, but it's better than nothing at all.

Comment: Thanks.  That seems to have worked.  I downloaded an rpm for version 1.5.5 that I figured might work, and it turned out I needed to install only one additional rpm--which was supplied in the same directory as the one I'd downloaded.

Comment: If you are adventurous, you can download the rpm packages for python using the same technique, and then force their re-installation.  That should revert your python back to the same version as yum was expecting.

Comment: Yes, I actually tried that:  downloaded for python 2.4; temporarily adjusted the PATH so the python command would use 2.4 instead of 2.7.  I haven't yet succeeded in getting yum working again; however, at least now it's complaining about a different module that it's not finding (sqlitecache).  I take that to imply I'm on the right track.  Meanwhile, back to learning Python.